# React Router V4 Implement NavLink inside a ListItem using Material UI

Tags: reactjs, list, react-router, navigation-drawer, material-ui

I am new to React and I created a simple application with **Login** and **Dashboard** page. I have successfully configured my **Public Routes** and **Private Routes** with **Redirect** functionalities. However when I want to implement [material-ui/core](https://material-ui.com/) Things are still quite working well but I can't achieve the **UI** that I want.

Here is my old implementation of my **NavBar** below:

```
const Navigation = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <NavLink exact to="/" activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>Home</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/about" activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>About</NavLink>
            <NavLink to="/contact" activeStyle={{ color: 'red' }}>Contact</NavLink>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Navigation
```

As simple as that with no **styling** or **classes**

But since I want to add some **styles** I used **material/ui core** and ended up doing the new one below:

```
export const MainNavigation = (
  <div>
    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <DashboardIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <ShoppingCartIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Orders" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <PeopleIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Customers" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <BarChartIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Reports" />
    </ListItem>
    <ListItem button>
      <ListItemIcon>
        <LayersIcon />
      </ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary="Integrations" />
    </ListItem>
  </div>
);
```

Now the first `ListItem` looks like this below:

[image]

But when I add this line of code below:

```
<ListItemText primary={<NavLink exact to="/">Dashboard</NavLink>} />
```

This is the result:

[image]

But I don't want this to happen.

I want to keep the first **UI** I dont wan't it to make it look like an **anchor tag** with a **under line below**

How can I also handle the **active state** of the `ListItem` in material/ui integrated with react router `NavLink` or `Link`? So that I can put some style or uses the active class of material.

Appreciate if someone could help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 44):

You can do it by setting the NavLink as the component of the list item. Here is an example that has worked for me!

```
<ListItem
  button
  key="Dashboard"
  component={NavLink} to="/dashboard"
>
    <ListItemIcon>
        <Dashboard />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText primary="Dashboard" />
</ListItem>
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: how to configure if one of the links is disabled?

Answer (score 31):

Use the component prop of ListItem. To get active route styling, set activeClassName of NavLink to Mui-selected.

```
<ListItem button component={NavLink} to="/" activeClassName="Mui-selected" exact>
  ...
</ListItem>
```

Comment: That works, but React complains: "Warning: React does not recognize the `activeClassName` prop on a DOM element. If you intentionally want it to appear in the DOM as a custom attribute, spell it as lowercase `activeclassname` instead. If you accidentally passed it from a parent component, remove it from the DOM element." Any ideas?

Comment: What version of react? What versions of material UI or react router? At the time I posted this, I did not get that error.

Comment: `"react": "^17.0.1"`, `"react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"`, `"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.2"`.

Comment: @ralfstx did you find any solution to this warning. 
  I am using MUI 5, and still getting this warning.