# React Material UI Menu overflow

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I make the main contents move correctly here. Looks like I need some dynamic calculation of margin left or what would be the best solution here?

Initially it looks OK:

[image]

But when the menu expands:

[image]

Or when the page gets resized:

[image]

Comment: Answer to this is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734659/react-router-v4-implement-navlink-inside-a-listitem-using-material-ui

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is the best practice, but this is how I solved similar problem.

Suppose your content looks like this.

```
<div class="main">
    <Menu class="menu" />
    <Content class="content" />
</div>
```

And style:

```
.main {
    display: flex;
}

.menu {
    width: 10vw;
}

.content {
    width: 90vw;
}

.menu__open {
    width: 25vw;
}

.content__on-menu-open {
    width: 75vw;
}
```

The last two classes are set when menu is opened.

PS: Styling for mobile will require additional classes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn't use the content in the right place.

Based on the answer here: [React Router V4 Implement NavLink inside a ListItem using Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53734659/react-router-v4-implement-navlink-inside-a-listitem-using-material-ui)

And also by using this

https://material-ui.com/components/drawers/#responsive-drawer

I was able to fix the problem.  Basically I was not outputting the content in the right place.